# Retrieve PID of selenium IE driver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

Is there any possible solution to get IE PID from java?
The problem is there are 8 instances of driver running concurrently. 
All I know that IEDriver can log PID in to the file.

```
Has Valid Protected Mode Settings: 0
Starting IE using the CreateProcess API
IE launched successfully with process ID 4192
Process with ID 4192 is executing iexplore.exe
Ignoring zoom setting: 0
rowser zoom level is 100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IE driver (and indeed the WebDriver API) does not expose the process ID of any of its running processes in any way. You'll need to rely on other methods (e.g., raw Windows API calls) to get this information. Also note that using those API calls, you're likely to run into race conditions with the IE driver code that will make the results difficult to interpret, so I would suggest reexamining why you assume having the PID is necessary for your use case.

Comment: I use one browser pool to share browsers between tests. After 1 hour of running tests IE browsers consume more than 1GB of RAM for each, because of memory leak. I suppose it happens because of https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3918. And I don't want to re-open browser before each test, it will significantly increase the total time of test execution. Therefore I want to monitor IE process and its RAM consumption by PID. Do you have any workaround for this?